# How do I obtain pseudo R2 measures in stata when using GLM regression?

Tags: statistics

I am using GLM estimation method (family = poisson and link = log). This should be equivalent to a poisson estimation method. Therefore, I should be able to calculate pseudo R2 measures. How can I do this?

Thanks,

Bruno

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pscl` package for this.

```
# Some mock data
set.seed(2014)
Y<-rpois(1000,4)
set.seed(2014)
x<-2*Y+0.1*rnorm(1000)

# Estimate model
require(MASS)
m1<-glm(Y~x,family="poisson"(link=log))

# Get Pseudo R²
require(pscl)
pR2(m1)

         llh          llhNull          G2      McFadden          r2ML          r2CU 
-1634.4075357 -2080.4918645   892.1686575     0.2144129     0.5902339     0.5995827
```

You can also calculate it yourself of course

```
# Estimate model with intercept only
m0<-glm(Y~1,family="poisson"(link=log))
R<-1-logLik(m1)/logLik(m0);R

'log Lik.' 0.2144129 (df=2)
```

Comment: Question pertains to Stata but your answer is for R.